# Etymology of "cut someone some slack"

Tags: etymology, idioms, american-english

> Teenagers. All the literature tells you one thing and one thing only – that  whatever they are doing, give them a break, **cut them some slack**, it's normal.
>
> <sub>From the novel, *Apple Tree Yard*</sub>

I'm curious about the origins of *[to cut some slack](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cut+some+slack)*. I know *slacks* are American English for trousers or pants, and a *slacker* is a lazy person. But what is a *slack* and how does one "cut" it?

Comment: slack is also the opposite of taut.  A taut line or leash doesn't allow much freedom of movement.  Putting some slack in the line allows more freedom of movement.  My guess is that this comes from sailing.

Comment: @Jim I've also heard something about the sailing theory, but not being particularly knowledgeable on the subject it would be great if you or someone else could confirm it.

Comment: I guess I've never thought about this.  I've always assumed that the "slack" was like slack in a rope.  A nautical origin is not unlikely, though the phrase is pretty ubiquitous, and I don't recall it being used in a nautical sense back when I was into sailboats.

Comment: (Although something is coming back to me, about "cutting slack" when "tightly hauled" against the wind.  It would let the boat "relax" in a way, heel over less, get pounded less by the wind and waves.  Or something like that.)

Comment: [This site](http://www.reddit.com/r/AskHistorians/comments/2p08a6/whats_the_origin_of_the_phrase_cut_me_some_slack/) gives some nautical context, but is not particularly authoritative.

Comment: Why the negation? Where is the insight? A good question!

Comment: Poor Pip gets caught in the *slack whale line* in [Moby-Dick](https://books.google.com/books?id=a6aaKXJTeaMC&pg=PA423&lpg=PA423&dq=whaling+cut+slack&source=bl&ots=S4ucBYgK5c&sig=YJZB2u-3v6QjHbdBsX2YIN-GaS8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=WoTNVLzwFYjfyATi7oCgCQ&ved=0CD0Q6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=whaling%20cut%20slack&f=false). An uncredible answer, [elsewhere](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20101102082857AASRA0R), makes a good point about angry whales pulling the boat under and that to 'cut slack' is an old whaling term.

Comment: *Cut me some slack* is probably not a metaphor of rope, but more likely of cooperage. Coopers, maintained a stock of two qualities of staves to build their barrels: high quality ***tight*** staves for barrels to hold water; and low quality ***slack*** staves, for barrels to hold dry goods. When a cooper said to his supplier, *"Cut me some slack* [staves]," the supplier understood that the quality expectation was significantly less. The expression came to mean: *lower your expectations please*. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooper_%28profession%29 Searching for evidence.

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=pfxYAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA6-PA36&lpg=RA6-PA36&dq=slack+staves&source=bl&ots=W1Guj5unjv&sig=X6HG6S8gQA_bKEf2sU_-CzCOa54&hl=en&sa=X&ei=JpnNVIOuNtW2yATw4oLwDA&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=slack%20staves&f=false

Comment: @ScotM - that is a worthy addition to answers (and undoubtedly correct). Will you post it? If you don't want to take the time, comment and I will.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm going away on vacation and will not have access to research tools to investigate this theory more deeply.

Comment: Another meaning of "slack" is the gravelly coal dust that is left over after the sizable lumps of coal are taken. This is low-quality and hard to manage to produce a steady fire. Of course a ton of slack would be a lot cheaper than a ton of lump coal too. "Cut" might then mean "mix" also - "I can't afford quality coal, mix in some slack". Total speculation, but another avenue for exploration.

Comment: @joffan interesting idea, if you can find any evidence to support it I'd love to hear it!

Comment: The [dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/) I've been using most defines [*slack*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/slack) roughly as *looseness*. *Cut me some slack*, therefore, would make perfect sense to me as a synonym of *give me a break* or *give me some space*.

Comment: @AndriyM I've done a bit of research myself, and personally I'm veering towards your interpretation and Jim's. But no one's brave enough to really back up the sailing theory. Still at least a few original ideas have been posted.

Comment: "Hangman, hangman,  slack your rope awhile." is a line in many versions of Child ballad #95.

Answer (score 26):

It is possible that the set phrase "cut someone some slack" is simply a metaphorical use of *cut* combined with a metaphorical use of *slack*:

> ***[Slack](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/slack)***
>
> ADJECTIVE
>
> 1.0 Not taut or held tightly in position; loose:
>
> 2.0 Having or showing laziness or negligence:

*Slack* can intuitively apply to **any standard** metaphorically: *neglect* your standard or *do not hold on tightly* to your standard.

> ***[Cut](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cut)***
>
> 3.2 Separate (something) into two; sever:

*Cut* can intuitively apply to **any standard** metaphorically: *Separate* a standard for me. The two words complement each other, so that *Cut me some slack* renders the meaning:

> *"Separate some loosely held standard for me."*

There are many plausible imaginative practical scenarios for metaphorical application:

- [Cooperage](http://www.en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooper_%28profession%29)
- [Maritime](http://www.harbourguides.com/news.php/NAUTICAL-SAYINGS-CUT-ME-SOME-SLACK): Mixed metaphor with "Give me some slack."
- [Masonry](https://books.google.com/books?id=E2EbAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA439&dq=%22cut%20slack%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=sl_UVKagFIifgwSA6oCIAg&ved=0CEwQ6AEwCDgy#v=onepage&q=%22cut%20slack%22&f=false): Documents of the Assembly of the State of New York, Volume
  3: 1847,page 439.
- [Colliery](https://books.google.com/books?id=sYVNAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA144&dq=machine-cut%20slack&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ZWfUVIKqE8OegwTpnoHwBA&ved=0CEIQ6AEwCDi0AQ#v=onepage&q=machine-cut%20slack&f=false): Minutes of Proceedings of the Institution of Civil Engineers, Volume 131: 1898, page 144.
- [Hanging](https://books.google.com/books?id=JvglAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA101&dq=%22cut%20slack%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=aWLUVJuSFoXVggS4joC4Bw&ved=0CBwQ6AEwADgo#v=onepage&q=%22cut%20slack%22&f=false): Adventures of the Comte de la Muette During the Reign of Terror: 1898, pages 100-101.
- [Electric Transmission](https://books.google.com/books?id=33sAAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA456&dq=%22cut%20slack%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=jmTUVIyxG4acNpTjgxg&ved=0CBwQ6AEwADgK#v=onepage&q=%22cut%20slack%22&f=false): Bulletin, Volume 4, By National Electric Light Association: 1911, page 456.

There is no **conclusive** evidence establishing any of these scenarios as the etymological source for *Cut me some slack*. It is quite possible that the broad practical use of the phrase *cut slack* established the metaphorical application as a set phrase. If there was a single practical source of the metaphorical application, the [cooperage](http://www.rootsweb.ancestry.com/~flbbm/heritage/cooper/barrelmaking.htm) application is most likely, for two reasons: it establishes an acceptable lower standard, and it was used far more extensively than any other practical application.

Coopers, maintained a stock of two qualities of staves to build their barrels: high quality ***tight*** staves for barrels to hold liquid goods; and low quality ***slack*** staves, for barrels to hold dry goods:

> [The Packages, Volume 24, November 1921, Page 36](https://books.google.com/books?id=pfxYAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA6-PA36&lpg=RA6-PA36&dq=slack%20staves&source=bl&ots=W1Guj5unjv&sig=X6HG6S8gQA_bKEf2sU_-CzCOa54&hl=en&sa=X&ei=JpnNVIOuNtW2yATw4oLwDA&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=slack%20staves&f=false)
>
> The terms "tight cooperage stock" and  "slack cooperage stock" are
>   applied by the trade to staves, beading and hoops used by coopers in
>   the manufacture or assembly of hogshead barrels, kegs, kits and
>   firkins. Tight cooperage stock pertains to containers for liquids, and
>   slack cooperage stock to containers for solids.

The *slack* cooperage industry was nearly twice as extensive as the tight cooperage industry, producing 50% **more** value with a significantly **less** valuable product:

> [Scientific American: Supplement, Volume 88](https://books.google.com/books?id=3AMiAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA229&dq=cut%20slack%20stave&hl=en&sa=X&ei=UzjUVLbCOIacgwSjnITYCA&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAzi0AQ#v=onepage&q=cut%20slack%20stave&f=false)
>
> The *slack* end of the business is the larger, judged by the quantity of
>   wood required to manufacture the product... The value of the *slack*
>   stock used in the country is nearly fifty percent more than the value
>   of tight material.

The forestry industry also referred to lower quality timber as ***slack*** cooperage blocks. To *cut slack* cooperage blocks referred to harvesting specific species of trees that meet lower *slack* cooperage quality specifications.

> [Forest Farmer Manual: 1955 - Page 66](https://books.google.com/books?id=3vgOAQAAMAAJ&q=%22cut%20slack%22&dq=%22cut%20slack%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ECnUVMqjOcqnNraQgtgH&ved=0CDkQ6AEwBjj6AQ)
>
> Generally several cuttings are made. In hardwood forests, the buyer or
>   the owner usually takes out sawlogs or veneer blocks first. He might
>   *cut slack* cooperage blocks or cross ties next, and finally make pulp-
>   wood and fuel from the tops.

Landowners, brokers, foresters, loggers, sawyers, suppliers, coopers, merchants, advertisers, machinists and government regulators in America all **expressed** a common notion of *cut slack* as *lower **acceptable** quality standard*. When a merchant said to his cooper, "Make me a *slack* [barrel]," they both understood that the quality expectation was significantly less than a tight barrel. When a cooper said to his supplier, "Bring me some *slack* [staves]," they both understood that the quality expectation was significantly less than tight staves. When the supplier said to his sawyer, "Cut me some *slack* [stock]," they both understood that the quality expectation was significantly less than tight stock. When the sawyer said to his logger, "Cut me some *slack* [logs]," they both understood that the quality expectation was significantly less than tight logs.

[Advertisers](https://books.google.com/books?id=Dec1AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA193&dq=cut%20slack%20stave&hl=en&sa=X&ei=UzjUVLbCOIacgwSjnITYCA&ved=0CCEQ6AEwATi0AQ#v=onepage&q=cut%20slack%20stave&f=false) made clear distinctions between all things *tight* and all things *slack*. [Machinists](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZsB8AAAAMAAJ&pg=PA392&dq=slack%20stave%20mill&hl=en&sa=X&ei=L0PUVN_dHIKpgwT1s4KwAQ&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAji0AQ#v=onepage&q=slack%20stave%20mill&f=false) designed and built separate mills to cut *slack* cooperage materials:

> [Cooperage: A Treatise on Modern Shop Practice and Methods, 1910, Page
>   194](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZsB8AAAAMAAJ&pg=PA392&dq=slack%20stave%20mill&hl=en&sa=X&ei=L0PUVN_dHIKpgwT1s4KwAQ&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAji0AQ#v=onepage&q=slack%20stave%20mill&f=false)
>
> Mills for the manufacture of *slack* stock are of various types...

The Federal Government established separate [regulations](https://books.google.com/books?id=3F00AAAAMAAJ&pg=PA220&dq=cut%20slack%20stave&hl=en&sa=X&ei=VzzUVJ_AHYmMsQSalIHYCA&ved=0CDIQ6AEwBDi-AQ#v=onepage&q=cut%20slack%20stave&f=false) for *[knife-cut slack staves](https://books.google.com/books?id=e_GyAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA1536&dq=knife-cut%20slack%20stave&hl=en&sa=X&ei=czXUVPeAB8e7ggTe04KoBQ&ved=0CD4Q6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=knife-cut%20slack%20stave&f=false)*.

In America, at least nine extensive interrelated industries were routinely exposed to the literal expression: *cut slack* with the connotation of ***acceptably*** lower quality standards. The cultural significance of cooperage from the 18th through 20th centuries supports a legitimate assumption:

> A a metaphorical application of the prevalent cooperage expression:
>
> - *"Cut me/you/him/us/them some slack [X].*"
>
> intuitively becomes:
>
> - *A lower standard is **acceptable***.

This is precisely what people mean when they say, "Cut me some slack!" metaphorically:

> *Your tight adherence to a higher standard is not necessary; a lower
>   standard is acceptable!*

The cooperage metaphor cannot be sited conclusive as the source of "*Cut me some slack*," but at minimum, the cooperage lingo extensively **supported** and **reinforce** the intuitive metaphorical application of *cut slack* in the culture, making the set phrase more suitable as an idiomatic ***[catch phrase](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/catchphrase)***.

Currently in Google Book search, the earliest confirmed use of "*Cut [x] some slack*" was the testimony of a young person explaining his perception of police aggression, transcribed in 1966:

> [Field Surveys - Issue 4, Volume 2 - Page 133](https://books.google.com/books?id=ALoJAAAAIAAJ&q=%22cut%20you%20some%20slack%22&dq=%22cut%20you%20some%20slack%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ghbUVNSBLYzsggTElIHYCQ&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA)
>
> Just the colored cop will do all the, you know, raising sand... Other
>   cop[s] will just sit back, you know. And he'll try and ***cut you some
>   slack***, but the colored cop won't, you know.
>
> ***Emphasis*** mine

http://www.rootsweb.ancestry.com/~flbbm/heritage/cooper/barrelmaking.htm

Comment: and now I want "Cut me some tight" to be a real phrase, too

Comment: Can you provide evidence to support your very plausible opinion that *Most likely when a cooper said to his supplier, "Cut me some slack [staves]," the supplier understood that the quality expectation was significantly less. The expression came to mean:

Lower your expectations please.*

Comment: Tongue in cheek, @Gus? *Segregate me in some more stringent standard* is not a common request. How many employees say: "Make me work though my lunch break, please?" :-)

Comment: Partly tongue in cheek.  My self-generated interpretation of the phrase would be used conversationally like this:  Person1 (sounding surprised) - "Wow, you really did a great job" Person2 (annoyed that Person1 is surprised)- "Hey, cut me some tight"

Comment: The quotation that your answer attributes to Frederick Douglass's _My Bondage and My Freedom_ (1855) is actually from Jack Cady's [_The Hauntings of Hood Canal_](https://books.google.com/books?id=tdR_nYc7P6AC&pg=PT34&dq=%22cut+slack+for+others+dumb+opinions%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi1-vO19-fQAhVK_WMKHWrLAvEQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22cut%20slack%20for%20others%20dumb%20opinions%22&f=false) (2011). So the first part of your answer is incorrect. I recommend editing the answer to delete the Douglass references and pick up at the words "[T]he literal underpinning of the expression..." in paragraph 3.

Comment: Contrary to my comment above, _The Hauntings of Hood Canal_ was published in 2001, not 2011. My apologies for the typo.

Comment: On April 8, 2017, I edited the first part of ScotM's otherwise quite interesting answer to remove the reference to a 2001 source of "cut some slack" that was included because ScotM thought it was from a much older (1855) source. The supposed early date of the now-deleted source was the only thing that made it relevant to this answer.

Answer (score 12):

One early match in a Google Books search for "cut me some slack" occurs in a glossary purportedly from Jack Sweetman, [*The U.S. Naval Academy, an Illustrated History*](https://books.google.com/books?id=AgTzAAAAMAAJ&q=%22cut+me+some+slack%22&dq=%22cut+me+some+slack%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=c8fNVMOeHom5oQTS3YKQBg&ved=0CD4Q6AEwBzgo) (1979) [snippet]:

> Slack — reduced discipline; see **Cut (Me) Some Slack**.

Unfortunately, we can't see "Cut (Me) Some Slack" because the book refuses to show a snippet view of that entry. And further research leads me to suspect that the snippet shown is actually from a mid-1990s edition of Ross MacKenzie, *Brief Points*, which (unlike Sweetman's book) does have a glossary of Naval Academy terms.

In any event, the sense of *cut* in this instance appears to be meaning 15.a. in J. E. Lighter, *Random House Historical Dictionary of American Slang* (1994):

> **15.a.** to favor with; to give. [Example:] 1972–76 Durden *No Bugles* 8: Aw, Sarge, cut us a break.

So "cut me some slack" = "favor me with reduced discipline" in 1970s (or 1990s) Middie-speak.

Robert Chapman & Barbara Kipfer, *Dictionary of American Slang*, third edition (1995) says "cut ... a break" was in use "by 1970s" and "cut ... some slack" was "1980s." That book interprets "cut [someone] some slack" as meaning "To stop pressuring or importuning someone; let someone be."

I haven't found any reference work that offers an explanation of what "cut some slack" might have meant originally, with actual slack and actual cutting in play. It is common for people working together on a rope to urge one another to "leave some slack" in the rope when possible, but I haven't come across any formal confirmation of this usage in connection with "cut ... some slack."

The Random House slang dictionary has only examples of "cut [someone] a break," not "cut [someone] some slack," but the meaning of the two phrases seems to be extremely similar.

---

***Early confirmed Google Books matches***

Another oldish Google Books match is from [*Revista Chicano-Riqueña*](https://books.google.com/books?id=auZ1AAAAMAAJ&q=%22cut+me+some+slack%22&dq=%22cut+me+some+slack%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=wMXNVP-yINLZoASCv4D4Dg&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAjge), volume 7 (1979):

> TERESA: I'm going to miss you, you big tonto. MANOLO: Who's tonto? TERESA: You are. MANOLO: **Cut me some slack**, mujer. TERESA: Tonto.
>
> ...
>
> MANOLO: Chale. I don't care about that. DOMINGO: But there are doctors and clinics... MANOLO: ¡Ya! I said no! DOMINGO: Then why don't you go along with el Louie? MANOLO: **Cut me some slack** will you? DOMINGO: You're scared aren't you? I can see you are scared.

Earlier still is this extract from Wyoming Highway Department Public Information Office, [*The Roadrunner*](https://books.google.com/books?id=0-06AQAAMAAJ&q=%22have+his+say,+and+then+proceeded+to%22&dq=%22have+his+say,+and+then+proceeded+to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ysjNVKrpOYvhoASo9oJo&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA) (1976) [combined snippets]:

> ...the officer **cut him some slack**. Then he went on to say how poorly he was treated and how tight the handcuffs were and how they hurt his wrists. He commented that he was peaceful and didn't need to be cuffed. He went on about how he had how he had to take the time to go to Cheyenne to appear in court and the money it cost him, etc.
>
> By this time, I'm sure you can see why my heart was breaking in two for the guy. I let him have his say, and then proceeded to set the record straight.

And from [Flying](https://books.google.com/books?id=P31WAAAAMAAJ&q=%22cut+us+some+slack%22&dq=%22cut+us+some+slack%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=wMnNVK_XCIqyogSD3oGICA&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAg), volume 98 (1976) [combined snippets]:

> Someone else had once taught me that good pilots don't accept a descent from ATC unless they are ready for it and know where they are. There are a lot of hard mountains in that area, fellas, so when we ask you to assure us of terrain clearance—we know it's still our responsibility to know that in spite of that nasty TWA mess—but **cut us some slack**, huh?

Neither of the 1976 magazine dates is definite, but both are circumstantially plausible. Several earlier would-be matches are clearly incorrectly dated in the Google Books database.

---

***Early confirmed newspaper database matches***

An Elephind newspaper database search finds five matches involving "cut [someone] some slack" from the 1970s—one from 1978, one from 1977, two from 1975, and one from 1972.

From "[Reader Supports Driver; Backs Humorus Comment](http://dks.library.kent.edu/cgi-bin/kentstate?a=d&d=dks19780531-01.2.13&txq=%22some+slack%22)," in the *[Kent, Ohio] Daily Kent Stater* (May 31, 1978):

> So, the next time you use the convenience of riding a campus bus, before you get on, **cut the driver some slack**. Maybe he’s more human than you think. (Anyway, if you’re at all good-looking, maybe he’s checking you out, too!)

From John Marchese, "[Marijuana Use in Dormitories](https://texashistory.unt.edu/ark:/67531/metapth332397/m1/2/zoom/?q=%22cut%20him%20some%20slack%22&resolution=4&lat=5227&lon=1808)," in the *[Denton, Texas] North Texas Daily* (February 18, 1977):

> "The first time I catch someone, I **cut him some slack**. If I catch him again then I'll have to take him to the director of housing."
>
> Other dormitories are not so lenient, but most RAs "**cut some slack**" on the first offense.

From "[Early Out During Xmas](https://texashistory.unt.edu/ark:/67531/metapth309224/m1/3/zoom/?q=%22some%20slack%22&resolution=6&lat=4641&lon=3392)," in the *[Temple, Texas] Fort Hood Sentinel* (December 4, 1975):

> Reserve component personnel undergoing active training and officers involuntarily separating on specified dates as directed by DA [Department of the Army] will separate regardless of the policy.
>
> The policy, however, **cuts some slack** for local commands. Officers who are involved in priority operations may be retained until their normal ETS [expiration of term of service] date if it is necessary.

From "[Misclassifieds](https://texashistory.unt.edu/ark:/67531/metapth245240/m1/11/zoom/?q=%22some%20slack%22&resolution=4&lat=3720&lon=1852)," in the *[Houston, Texas] Rice Thresher* (April 24, 1975):

> Rob—**cut me some slack**!—Graz.
>
> Leiter—**Cut me some slack**.— Rob.

And from "[Smoking Dopes](http://digitalnewspapers.libraries.psu.edu/Olive/APA/collegian/#panel=search&search=1)," in the *[State College, Pennsylvania] Daily Collegian* (November 9, 1972):

> I suppose the reader may be asking himself, "doesn't this guy appreciate a cheap drunk; a chance to get up on quality hash for  free; an opportunity to groove on Isaac [Hates], while getting vicariously stoned? "At the risk of sounding like an ingrate" —Hell no, I keenly resent it!
>
> I see three possible means of rectifying this respiratory rape:
>
> 1. Students attending concerts can **cut the non-heads in attendance some slack** by leaving their "J's" at home instead of ruthlessly bludgeoning these fellow students into submission with them.

These five instances from 1972–1978 (all of which come from U.S. university or military base sources) seem to use the expression "cut [someone] a break" in the still-current sense of "go easy on [someone]," "be lenient with [someone]," or "give [someone] someone some leeway."

And finally, as Jacob Lyles points out in a comment beneath this answer, a list of new expressions in [*Idioma*](https://books.google.com/books?id=t1M8AAAAIAAJ&dq=%22society+of+an+elite+group+with+which+the+drug+user+identifies+himself%3A+aristocratic+disdain+for%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22Hey%2C+man%2C+cut+me+some+slack%22), volumes 5–6 (1968), page 58, includes this entry (and translation):

> Hey, man, **cut me some slack**. [Translation:] Hey, buddy, take it easy.

A more accurate translation of this wording might be "Hey, buddy, loosen up on me."

Comment: Super! I would have sworn the expression was dated from the 40s or 50s. I'm quite astonished to discover it's so "new", finding this expression in a *very* British novel written by someone who grew up in the East Midlands was also a bit of a surprise.

Comment: Have you tried searching for "to give (someone) some slack"? There's the expression "give me a break" which has a similar meaning to "cut some slack".

Comment: I just did a quick check and "give [me] some slack" is indeed older. One example, from _Memo—Go Fishing_, dates to 1931, supposedly, and refers to catching a fish: "I was afraid every minute that the hook wouldn't hold and eventually, when I got this still milling and resentful nine-pounder close to the canoe, Bill said: "Give him some slack." The same advice is offered elsewhere in connection with dog training, horse training, working as a longshoreman, etc., etc. Of course, in those cases "give him some slack" is meant literally. Good point, Mari-Lou A.

Comment: For what it's worth, etymyonline dates this usage to 1968 (see: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=slack&allowed_in_frame=0), so this origin is plausible. I'm sending the maintainer an email for his source.

Comment: The owner of etymyonline says "You can find it in a list of new expressions in Idioma vol. 5-6 (1968)"

Comment: @JacobLyles: Belated thanks for the 1968 reference and for following up with the proprietor of Etymology Online for his source. It's the earliest (by four years!) printed instance of the expression I've seen.

Answer (score 4):

> #### GIVE ME SOME SLACK
>
> Still very much in use today and probably thought by most people as being relatively modern in origin, the phrase ‘give me some slack’ or ‘cut me some slack’ (meaning make allowances to complete something) is actually hundreds of years old. Tying a ship to a pier was no easy feat and took two teams of men armed with mooring lines. As one line was pulled to haul the ship closer the other line was released or ‘given slack’. The process would go on until the ship was properly aligned.

http://www.harbourguides.com/news.php/NAUTICAL-SAYINGS-CUT-ME-SOME-SLACK

Comment: I found the comment posted in the link to be quite persuasive...

Answer (score 1):

Without thinking about it, I always felt it had to do with rope, because it was a common saying in the Navy around 1968. I meant "give me a break- ease up on me."

Comment: How about supporting your answer with a reference?

Answer (score 0):

[Cut somebody some slack](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cut+some+slack)  (American & Australian informal):

> - to allow someone to do something that is not usually allowed, or to treat someone less severely than is usual.
>     *Officials have asked the Environmental Protection Agency to cut Utah some slack in enforcing the Clean Air Act*.

According to [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=slack):

slack: (early 14c., "cessation" (of pain, grief, etc.), from slack (adj.)

> - slang: cut (someone) some slack (1968).

I think 'cut' is used to mean 'reduce' (the pain, tension etc.)

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cut+some+slack&year_start=1960&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccut%20some%20slack%3B%2Cc0): cut some slack (American English corpus)
[image]

Comment: @Josh61- I think you read it wrong... the expression "cut some slack" is not connected to the definition you provided in your answer, but to the following: "a loose end of rope or sail" - which appears later in the same paragraph. My personal instinct is that the expression hints at someone being unjustly hanged (for some offense) and begs to loosen the rope.

Comment: Oh, well suit yourself. You could have legitimized updating your answer because you found "new" evidence which links *cut a deal* with *cut some slack*. (That's what I would have done)

Comment: It is not a question of suiting myself; the origin of 'cut' used in 'cut a deal' has little/nothing to do with my (wrong) answer here. How can I reasonably fit it into my context? A correct answer and other useful ones have already been given.

Answer (score 0):

"Give me some slack", in the figurative sense, appears to have been used in *The Movement Toward a New America* by Mitchell Goodman in [1970](https://books.google.com/books?id=Rm8nAQAAMAAJ&q=%22give+me+some+slack%22&dq=%22give+me+some+slack%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZ8Pr4jvjSAhUUVWMKHZ0VDkk4ChDoAQgkMAI):

> "For three weeks in a row, 'Sky Pilot' was number one in Bien Hoa.  I
>   keep thinking of the line, 'A young soldier so ill/Looks at the sky
>   pilot, remembers the words, "Thou Shall Not Kill".' Man, **give me some
>   slack**, huh. Thank God for the sense of sound."—An MP in Vietnam.

And this appears to be attributed to *Rolling Stone*, 11/9/68.

"Cut him some slack" appears in *Die nigger die!* by Herbert Rap Brown in [1970](https://books.google.com/books?id=GqEKAQAAIAAJ&q=%22cut+him+some+slack%22&dq=%22cut+him+some+slack%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj5yLSIkfjSAhUI1GMKHTH9AIc4ChDoAQgbMAA):

> Now, if the brother couldn't come back behind that, I usually **cut him
>   some slack** (depending on time, place and his attitude). We learned
>   what the white folks call verbal skills. We learned how to throw them
>   words together.

Occurrences of "give me some slack", in the literal sense, go back to 1908, but "cut me/him some slack" doesn't seem to have had much literal use.

Comment: Where do you think *slack* originates from? Is it a naval, sailing term? Or something totally different?

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Ngram finds show that "give me/him some slack" is a term used in several contexts -- naval, for letting out on a rope, workmen in trees or on tall building, for similarly letting out rope, and horsemen, for loosening the reins.  These are all obvious literal uses.

Answer (score -4):

Your question actually requires resolving two questions

1. etymology of idiomatic use of *cut*
2. etymology of idiomatic *cut some slack*

#### Cut

I can only respond within my own cultural environment for the idiomatic use of the word cut.

Cutting covenant = cutting a deal

Genesis 15:18

ביום ההוא כרת יי את אברם ברית
In that day *cut* the LORD with Abram a covenant.

The use of the Hebrew word *cut* to represent "cutting a deal" is repeated at least 15 times in the Bible. Psalm 105:9 speaks of the LORD cutting an oath with Isaac.

OTOH, even for Christians who read the Bible in English or any other language besides Hebrew, and the word *cut* is not obvious in most English Bibles, they do promote the idiom *cut in stone* as an idea of religious origin, since the tablets of the commandments were first cut in stone.

Regardless if you like it or not, we can safely say many English words and idioms have biblical origins. If biblical origins were not the first use of the idiomatic use of the word *cut*, I believe the popularity of such idiomatic use would never have taken off if not for the prevalent and popular understanding of biblical concept of cutting covenant and commandments in stone.

Similarly, I believe that the popularity of idiomatic phrase *cut me a deal* would not have taken off if not for the latent religious concept.

#### Slack

*Slack* as a spontaneous idiomatic idea should probably have been in use since humans acquired speech.

The idiom *Let me some slack*, is a phrase that is spontaneous to every culture, not just to English.

Where *slack* has come to mean *lax*, *lack of stringency*. It could well have come from old germanic origins to mean slag (dross) - i.e., unwanted residue.

- Don't overwork me to have me remove every bit of slag. Allow me some slag.

With the popularity of biblical perspective in the English speaking world, one could well expect people to transfer the phrase

> Let/allow me some slack

to

> Cut me some slack.

Comment: I have a feeling my answer will annoy trigger-happy down-voters.

Comment: Thank you for picking up on the usage of "cut" in your answer, but I doubt the meaning of *cut* as in "to reduce" or "to allow" derives from the Bible. I have never heard of the idiom "let me some slack", I think you should find some evidence that proves it existed prior to "cut some slack".

Comment: After a mere eight months an upvote for the Biblical origin of "cut a deal", which has cropped up in [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/284233/why-do-we-cut-a-deal) today